# How can I force Hibernate to use joins to fetch data for instances

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application using Hibernate as JPA provider. My application has two entities connected with a `@OneToMany` / `@ManyToOne` relation.  The relation is annotated with `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` on both directions, and `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`.

My entities are called `Car` and `Driver`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
@Data
public class Car implements Serializable, Cloneable {
   @Id
   @GenericGenerator(name = "car_seq", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator", parameters = {
   @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "car_seq") })
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "car_seq")
   private Integer id;
    
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   private List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<>();
    
   @Column(name = "license_no", nullable = false)
   private String licenseNo;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "driver")
@Data
public class Driver implements Serializable, Cloneable {
   @Id
   @GenericGenerator(name = "driver_seq", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator", parameters = {
   @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "driver_seq") })
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "driver_seq")
   private Integer id;
    
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", nullable = true)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   private Car car;
    
   @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
   private String name;
}
```

When selecting a care (e.g. by calling `Car.findById()`), Hibernate joins the the two tables in a single SQL, and returns a `Car` object with a list of `Drivers`.

But if I select a single driver, Hibernate will join the `Driver` and `Car` table to give me the `Driver` object with the `Car` property populated, but it will run a second query to fetch all the driver objects on  for the list on the car object.

For performance reasons I would like all the involved objects to be fetched in a single query, as is the case when I fetch a car.  But I cannot find a way to make Hibernate do this. There is a property, `hibernate.max_fetch_depth`, which is supposed to do this, but I have found that it only affects the behavior of fetching a car, not when I fetch a driver.

I know I can use an `EntityGraph` to control the fetching, and by using an `EntityGraph` I have successfully retrieved a driver object with its car and all the car's drivers in one query.  But to do that, I have to explicitly use a graph when retrieving the object, and I cannot do that in all the various cases where a `Car` object is needed.  There are lots of other entities that have a relation to `Car`, and I don't want to write an `EntityGraph` for each and every one of those.

So is there a way to tell Hibernate how you want the fetching to be done by default on an entity? I would have thought that the annotations would be enough, but it seems that there either has to be something more, or that this simply cannot be done.

Arndt

Answer (score 3):

`FetchType.EAGER` is one of the most common reasons for performance problems. You should use

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
private List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<>();
```

And fetch drivers If needed

`SELECT c FROM Car c JOIN FETCH c.drivers`

Comment: Thank you trying to help, but I really need to solve this with eager fetching using join. Using lazy loading is not an option in this case, since I almost always need to access the drivers.

Comment: By default `@OneToMany` is fetch = FetchType.LAZY

Comment: You never know the use-cases will be necessary for the application. If you opt for `FetchType.EAGER`, it will be difficult (or even impossible) to change in the future. `FetchType.LAZY` is a far more flexible solution